# need to get a specific value from a list within a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and a value `x`. if `x` is in any of the inner lists, I want get the other value in that particular list.

For example:

```
mainlist  = [[a,b],[c,d],[a,d]]  
val = a  

for lst in mainlist:
    if val in lst:
        # I want b and d
```

Comment: Just for practice, I implemented this in Haskell. Find it [here](https://repl.it/JITM/4)

Comment: Pretty cool!! Another language to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a list comprehension, you can do something like this:

```
[[e for e in s if e != val] for s in mainlist if val in s]
# [['b'], ['d']]
```

Or use a nested for loop:

```
result = []
​
for s in mainlist:
    if val in s:
        for e in s:
            if e != val:
                result.append(e)

result
# ['b', 'd']
```

Comment: I wonder if it would be faster to do `for s in mainlist: if val in s: result.extend(s)` then `final = [x for x in result if x != val]`

Comment: Thanks all!! I appreciate the quick resonses

Answer (score 0):

Use a really awesome list comprehension:

```
search_val = a
values = [other for inner_list in mainlist for other in inner_list if a in inner_list if other != a]
```